# Ragdoll armature

Tags: armature, physics

I have an armature rig for a horse, and I want to know how I would create ragdoll physics on the armature, so that I could have a ragdoll horse. What should I do?

Comment: Is this for use in blender, the bge, or something else like unreal engine?

Comment: I'm using it in blender.

Comment: Anybody? I have no idea what to do and the tutorials I watched made no sense